# Template element workaround in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Is there any workaround to use `<template>` element in IE & Edge ?

Example of what I use `<template>` element for

```
<template id="template-comment">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="input-comment-{ID}-number" name="input-comment-{ID}-number">
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="input-comment-{ID}-text" name="input-comment-{ID}-text">
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

And JavaScript use of template

```
var i = 1;

function NewComment()
{
    $("#tbody-comments").append(ReplaceAll($("#template-comment").html(), "{ID}", i++));
}

function ReplaceAll(string, find, replace) { ... }
```

Comment: Try this polyfill - https://github.com/WebComponents/webcomponentsjs

Comment: For what it's worth, Microsoft is currently working on implementing the `<template>` element in Edge.

Comment: For backward compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution without polyfill: 
Instead of `<template>` just use `<script type="text/x-html-template">` - this will even work in IE and Edge for mobile devices (which seems to be different to Edge on Desktop).

Answer (score 1):

If you only need `<template>` you can download webcomponents-lite.js from https://github.com/WebComponents/webcomponentsjs#releases .

The template element is [under development](https://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/templateelement/) in Microsoft Edge, and will be included in a future update, so this will not be needed for Edge in the long run, especially with Edge being an evergreen auto-updating browser.

You can read more about our plans for Template and the other web component specs on the Edge blog: [Part 1](http://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/14/bringing-componentization-to-the-web-an-overview-of-web-components/) and [Part 2](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2015/07/15/microsoft-edge-and-web-components/)